# Exit a Script On Error

Tags: bash, exit, shell

I'm building a Shell Script that has a `if` function like this one:

```
if jarsigner -verbose -keystore $keyst -keystore $pass $jar_file $kalias
then
    echo $jar_file signed sucessfully
else
    echo ERROR: Failed to sign $jar_file. Please recheck the variables
fi

...
```

I want the execution of the script to finish after displaying the error message. How I can do this?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Are you looking for [`exit`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)?

This is the best bash guide around.
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

In context:

```
if jarsigner -verbose -keystore $keyst -keystore $pass $jar_file $kalias
then
    echo $jar_file signed sucessfully
else
    echo ERROR: Failed to sign $jar_file. Please recheck the variables 1>&2
    exit 1 # terminate and indicate error
fi

...
```

Comment: If you like the ABS, you'll love the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: Those Bash links are AWESOME!  The BashFAQ would be better positioned as BashRecipes.

Answer (score 370):

If you put **`set -e`** in a script, the script will terminate as soon as any command inside it fails (i.e. as soon as any command returns a nonzero status). This doesn't let you write your own message, but often the failing command's own messages are enough.

The advantage of this approach is that it's automatic: you don't run the risk of forgetting to deal with an error case.

Commands whose status is tested by a conditional (such as `if`, `&&` or `||`) do not terminate the script (otherwise the conditional would be pointless). An idiom for the occasional command whose failure doesn't matter is `command-that-may-fail || true`. You can also turn `set -e` off for a part of the script with `set +e`.

Comment: According to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 - this feature has a history of being obscure and convoluted in its determination of which commands' error codes cause an automatic exit.  Furthermore, "the rules change from one Bash version to another, as Bash attempts to track the extremely slippery POSIX definition of this 'feature'".  I agree with @Dennis Williamson and the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script - use trap 'error_handler' ERR.  Even if it's a trap!

Comment: often using the `-x` flag with the `-e` flag is enough of a trace on where your program is on exit. That implies that the user of the script is also the developer.

Comment: Nice but I think the OP needed to exit the script from a self-defined exception.

Comment: This is not a good design. There's arithmetic operations than can break your script when you don't expect this to happens

Answer (score 47):

If you want to be able to handle an error instead of blindly exiting, instead of using `set -e`, use a `trap` on the `ERR` pseudo signal.

```
#!/bin/bash
f () {
    errorCode=$? # save the exit code as the first thing done in the trap function
    echo "error $errorCode"
    echo "the command executing at the time of the error was"
    echo "$BASH_COMMAND"
    echo "on line ${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
    # do some error handling, cleanup, logging, notification
    # $BASH_COMMAND contains the command that was being executed at the time of the trap
    # ${BASH_LINENO[0]} contains the line number in the script of that command
    # exit the script or return to try again, etc.
    exit $errorCode  # or use some other value or do return instead
}
trap f ERR
# do some stuff
false # returns 1 so it triggers the trap
# maybe do some other stuff
```

Other traps can be set to handle other signals, including the usual Unix signals plus the other Bash pseudo signals `RETURN` and `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

abort()
{
    echo >&2 '
***************
*** ABORTED ***
***************
'
    echo "An error occurred. Exiting..." >&2
    exit 1
}

trap 'abort' 0

set -e

# Add your script below....
# If an error occurs, the abort() function will be called.
#----------------------------------------------------------
# ===> Your script goes here
# Done!
trap : 0

echo >&2 '
************
*** DONE *** 
************
'
```

Comment: Why the DONE message to stderr?

Comment: This is a common practice so you can pipe your script output to stdout so another process can get it without having the info messages in the middle.

Comment: It is probably equally common practice to treat anything on stderr as an indication of problems.

Comment: In the past 'set -e' has always worked for me, but tonight I ran across a situation in an Alpine Linux Docker image where it had no effect.. This solution worked for me and got me back on the task at hand. Much appreciated.

Comment: @supercobra Common practice?  Where?