# What does 'set -e' mean in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm studying the content of this **preinst** file that the script executes before that package is unpacked from its [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) archive (.deb) file.

The script has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ "$1" = install ]; then
   if [ -d /usr/share/MyApplicationName ]; then
     echo "MyApplicationName is just installed"
     return 1
   fi
   rm -Rf $HOME/.config/nautilus-actions/nautilus-actions.conf
   rm -Rf $HOME/.local/share/file-manager/actions/*
fi
# End automatically added section
```

My first query is about the line:

```
set -e
```

I think that the rest of the script is pretty simple: It checks whether the Debian/[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) package manager is executing an install operation. If it is, it checks whether my application has just been installed on the system. If it has, the script prints the message **"MyApplicationName is just installed"** and ends (`return 1` mean that ends with an “error”, doesn’t it?).

If the user is asking the Debian/Ubuntu package system to install my package, the script also deletes two directories.

Is this right or am I missing something?

Comment: [set -e](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error)

Comment: reason why you couldn't find this in google: -e in your query is interpreted as negation. Try following query: bash set "-e"

Comment: @twalberg When I've asked myself the same question, I was looking at `man set`

Comment: if you're looking how to turn it off, swap the dash to a plus prefix: `set +e`

Comment: @twalberg but asking real people is so much more interesting than just making a request from a robot ;-).

Comment: @2GN The jury's still out... I'm not entirely convinced every questioner/commenter/answerer I've ever encountered on SO and family is "real people" and not a robot... ;-)

Comment: It is explained here
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-set-+e-and-set-e-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1140, accepted):

From `help set` and [*Bash Reference Documentation: The Set Builtin*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set):

```
  -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

But it's considered bad practice by some (Bash FAQ and [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) #bash FAQ authors). It's recommended to use:

```
trap 'do_something' ERR
```

to run `do_something` function when errors occur.

See *[Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)*

Comment: What would the do_something be if I wanted the same semantics as "Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status"?

Comment: when exiting in this way, you also get a non-zero status

Comment: The `ERR` trap is not inherited by shell functions, so if you have functions,  `set -o errtrace` or `set -E` will allow you to just set the trap once and apply it globally.

Comment: @Conan, how about `trap 'exit 1' ERR`? I must admit, I'm not familiar with exactly when `ERR` fires. Is it like `set -e` or `set -o pipefail`? Or something else?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm afraid I no longer have access to the environment where I was doing this stuff (previous job), and I can't quite remember the setup.  I was never an expert at this, maybe someone else knows more about `ERR`?

Comment: does `trap 'exit' ERR` do *anything* different from `set -e`?

Comment: if it's bad practice then why it's used in [Debian packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325705/44425)?

Comment: It's *not* universally considered bad practice.  As with many disfavored language construct, it has its place.  The main problem with it is that the behavior in edge cases is  somewhat non-intuitive.

Comment: I, too, disagree that it's considered bad practice. The link you provided mentions its not a complete solution and that there are gotchas, as is the case with any type of programming solution. There's a right time to use it and a wrong time to use it. As rking states in the article you linked to, "It has useful semantics, so to exclude it from the toolbox is to give into FUD."

Comment: @GuyPaddock, ...the usernames may not mean much to folks who haven't spent time in the freenode #bash channel, but the people on the "set -e shouldn't be used" side of that debate are known entities -- greycat wrote the BashFAQ in the first place; geirha wrote a bunch of tooling including the "evalbot" sandbox used for testing commands in isolated VMs. This is an argument-from-authority, sure, but as someone who spent a decade there, I have no idea who this "RKing" person is, but I surely *do* know the people they're disagreeing with.

Comment: ...and insofar as the people they're disagreeing with are folks with a lot of time/experience trying to provide support to users of bash in the real world (and thus learning about where and how new users get tripped up), the extent to which that experience informs their beliefs about which language features are best avoided is probably worth some attention. Similarly, I'd trust someone who's spent years helping debug JavaScript written by n00bs to that language to know which language features are error-prone and best avoided more than I would some random JS developer.

Comment: This can also be achieved adding `-e` to the shebang see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15998/what-does-the-e-do-in-a-bash-shebang

Comment: The answer is not details, it's not clear what neither 'do_something' nor ERR means.
The provided link doesn't explain it at all. In fact, they mention `trap` only once in the question. An example would have more sense.

Comment: After the hostile takeover in 2021, the successor to [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) is ***[Libera Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libera_Chat)***.

Answer (score 205):

`set -e` stops the execution of a script if a command or pipeline has an error - which is the opposite of the default shell behaviour, which is to ignore errors in scripts. Type `help set` in a terminal to see the documentation for this built-in command.

Comment: It only stops execution if the **last** command in a pipeline has an error. There's a Bash specific option, `set -o pipefail` which can be used to propagate errors so that the return value of the pipeline command is non-zero if one of the preceding commands exited with a non-zero status.

Comment: Keep in mind that `-o pipefail` means only that the *exit status* of the first non-zero (i.e. erroring in `-o errexit` terms) command of the pipeline is propagated to the end. The remaining commands in the pipeline *still run*, even with `set -o errexit`. For example: `echo success | cat - <(echo piping); echo continues`, where `echo success` represents a successful, but fallible command, will print `success`, `piping`, and `continues`, but `false | cat - <(echo piping); echo continues`, with `false` representing the command now erroring silently, will still print `piping` before exiting.

Comment: Important distinction: `set -e` exits the script when a command has a non-zero exist status, which does not *always* mean an error occurred. `grep`, for example, has an exit status of 1 when it fails to find a match, but that's not an error.

Comment: It would be better to say `*simple* command`.   The shell will not exit if a compound command fails, and this distinction is a cause of a vast amounts of confusion and grief.

Answer (score 111):

I found this post while trying to figure out what the exit status was for a script that was aborted due to a `set -e`. The answer didn't appear obvious to me; hence this answer. Basically, *`set -e` aborts the execution of a command (e.g. a shell script) and returns the exit status code of the command that failed (i.e. the inner script, not the outer script)*.

For example, suppose I have the shell script `outer-test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
./inner-test.sh
exit 62;
```

The code for `inner-test.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 26;
```

When I run `outer-script.sh` from the command line, my outer script terminates with the exit code of the inner script:

```
$ ./outer-test.sh
$ echo $?
26
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail about the return status code :+1:.

Answer (score 73):

As per [bash - The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) manual, if `-e`/`errexit` is set, the shell exits immediately if a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) consisting of a single [simple command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html#Simple-Commands), [a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) or [a compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html#Compound-Commands) returns a non-zero status.

By default, the exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled (it's disabled by default).

If so, the pipeline's return status of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

If you'd like to execute something on exit, try defining `trap`, for example:

```
trap onexit EXIT
```

where `onexit` is your function to do something on exit, like below which is printing the simple [stack trace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19323/21471):

```
onexit(){ while caller $((n++)); do :; done; }
```

There is similar option [`-E`/`errtrace`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25378845/55075) which would trap on ERR instead, e.g.:

```
trap onerr ERR
```

#### Examples

Zero status example:

```
$ true; echo $?
0
```

Non-zero status example:

```
$ false; echo $?
1
```

Negating status examples:

```
$ ! false; echo $?
0
$ false || true; echo $?
0
```

Test with `pipefail` being disabled:

```
$ bash -c 'set +o pipefail -e; true | true | true; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
$ bash -c 'set +o pipefail -e; false | false | true; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
$ bash -c 'set +o pipefail -e; true | true | false; echo success'; echo $?
1
```

Test with `pipefail` being enabled:

```
$ bash -c 'set -o pipefail -e; true | false | true; echo success'; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 32):

None of the other answers here discuss the use of `set -e` aka `set -o errexit` in Debian package handling scripts. The use of this option is *mandatory* in these scripts, per Debian policy; the intent is apparently to avoid any possibility of an unhandled error condition.

In practice, this means that you have to understand under what conditions the commands you run could return an error, and handle each of those errors explicitly.

Common gotchas are, e.g., `diff` (returns an error when there is a difference) and `grep` (returns an error when there is no match). You can avoid the errors with explicit handling:

```
diff this that ||
  echo "$0: there was a difference" >&2
grep cat food ||
  echo "$0: no cat in the food" >&2
```

(Notice also how we take care to include the current script's name in the message, and writing diagnostic messages to standard error instead of standard output.)

If no explicit handling is really necessary or useful, explicitly do nothing:

```
diff this that || true
grep cat food || :
```

(The use of the shell's `:` no-op command is slightly obscure, but fairly commonly seen.)

Just to reiterate,

```
something || other
```

is shorthand for

```
if something; then
    : nothing
else
    other
fi
```

i.e., we explicitly say `other` should be run if and only if `something` fails. The longhand `if` (and other shell flow control statements like `while`, `until`) is also a valid way to handle an error (indeed, if it weren't, shell scripts with `set -e` could never contain flow control statements!)

And also, just to be explicit, in the absence of a handler like this, `set -e` would cause the entire script to immediately fail with an error if `diff` found a difference, or if `grep` didn't find a match.

On the other hand, some commands don't produce an error exit status when you'd want them to. Commonly problematic commands are `find` (exit status does not reflect whether files were actually found) and `sed` (exit status won't reveal whether the script received any input or actually performed any commands successfully). A simple guard in some scenarios is to pipe to a command which does scream if there is no output:

```
find things | grep .
sed -n 's/o/me/p' stuff | grep ^
```

It should be noted that the exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in that pipeline. So the above commands actually completely mask the status of `find` and `sed`, and only tell you whether `grep` finally succeeded.

(Bash, of course, has `set -o pipefail`, which throws an error if any command in a pipeline failed; but Debian package scripts cannot use Bash features. The policy firmly dictates the use of POSIX `sh` for these scripts, though this was not always the case.)

In many situations, this is something to separately watch out for when coding defensively. Sometimes you have to e.g. go through a temporary file so you can see whether the command which produced that output finished successfully, even when idiom and convenience would otherwise direct you to use a shell pipeline.

Comment: this is an excellent answer. and it promotes the best practice. I had exactally the same problem from GREP command and i really did not want to remove the 'set -e'

Comment: Of course, [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) doesn't work at all with `set -e`; but there are already many other reasons to avoid that antipattern.

Answer (score 30):

**set -e** The **set -e** option instructs Bash to immediately exit if any command [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) **has a non-zero exit status**. You wouldn't want to set this for your command-line shell, but in a script it's massively helpful.

In all widely used general-purpose programming languages, an unhandled runtime error - whether that's a thrown exception in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), or a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), or a syntax error in [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) - immediately halts execution of the program; subsequent lines are not executed.

- By default, Bash does not do this. This default behavior is exactly what you want if you are using Bash on the command line
- you don't want a typo to log you out! But in a script, you really want the opposite.
- If one line in a script fails, but the last line succeeds, the whole script has a successful exit code. That makes it very easy to miss the error.
- Again, what you want when using Bash as your command-line shell and using it in scripts are at odds here. Being intolerant of errors is a lot better in scripts, and that's what `set -e` gives you.

Copied from: *[Bash strict mode](https://gist.github.com/mohanpedala/1e2ff5661761d3abd0385e8223e16425)*

Comment: "This default behavior is exactly what you want if you are using bash on the command line" -- to be more clear: if you use `set -e` when running bash commands a simple typo could cause your bash session to just exit immediately. Try running a new terminal, `set -e`, then `lsd`. Bye goes terminal.

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Comment: There isn't *any* original contribution here (wholesale copied). The *** *** ***absolute minimum*** *** *** is quoting.

Comment: The original source is *[Use Bash strict mode (unless you love debugging)](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)*.

Answer (score 27):

I believe the intention is for the script in question to fail fast.

To test this yourself, simply type `set -e` at a Bash prompt. Now, try running `ls`. You'll get a directory listing. Now, type `lsd`. That command is not recognized and will return an error code, and so your Bash prompt will close (due to `set -e`).

Now, to understand this in the context of a 'script', use this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -e

lsd

ls
```

If you run it as is, you'll get the directory listing from the `ls` on the last line. If you uncomment the `set -e` and run again, you won't see the directory listing as bash stops processing once it encounters the error from `lsd`.

Comment: Does this answer add any insight or information that wasn't already given in others on the question?

Comment: I think it offers a clear, succinct explanation of the functionality that is not present in the other answers. Nothing additional, just more focused than the other responses.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it does. It is much more useful than just saying "look at the man page"

Comment: The other answer _doesn't_ just say "look at the man page" -- it pulls out the specific part of the man page that's relevant and important. It's the failure to be specific (and the requirement that the reader then do their own research) that makes "look at the man page" unhelpful.

Comment: I also think this answer is helpful @CharlesDuffy

Comment: great vivid example!

Answer (score 14):

Script 1: without setting `-e`

```
#!/bin/bash
decho "hi"
echo "hello"
```

This will throw an error in the line with `decho` and the program continues to the next line.

Script 2: With setting `-e`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
decho "hi"
echo "hello"
```

Up to `decho "hi"`, the shell will process and the program exit. It will not proceed further.

Answer (score 6):

It stops execution of a script if a command fails.

A notable exception is an `if` statement. eg:

```bash
set -e
false
echo never executed
```

```bash
set -e
if false; then
  echo never executed
fi

echo executed

false

echo never executed
```

Comment: This seems like merely another repetition of many of the previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat a.sh
#! /bin/bash

#going forward report subshell or command exit value if errors
#set -e
(cat b.txt)
echo "hi"

./a.sh; echo $?
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
hi
0
```

with set -e commented out we see that echo "hi" exit status being reported and hi is printed.

```
cat a.sh
#! /bin/bash

#going forward report subshell or command exit value if errors
set -e
(cat b.txt)
echo "hi"

./a.sh; echo $?
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
1
```

Now we see b.txt error being reported instead and no hi printed.

So default behaviour of shell script is to ignore command errors and continue processing and report exit status of last command.  If you want to exit on error and report its status we can use -e option.

Answer (score 0):

`set -e` means that the reader of the script cannot know what the script will do when looking at code snippets out of context.  (This is a bit tongue-in-cheek, but gets to the heart of the matter.)  I have been opposed to the use of `errexit` for many years and have recently been doing a fair bit of work in an environment where shell snippets are accumulated as templates.  `errexit` is enabled by default in this environment, but that is largely irrelevant as any previous snippet may disable errexit and the order in which the templates are gathered is not well known and probably non-deterministic.  But consider the simple case in which you look at a few lines without context in a shell script:

```
$ sed -n 3,6p sample-script 
echo this will be printed
set -e  # enable errexit again just to be sure it's on
false
echo but errexit is enabled so this will not be printed
```

Since errexit is enabled, the reader is being very reasonable in expecting that the line "but errexit is enabled so this will not be printed" will not in fact be written.  But, consider the actual execution of the script:

```
$ ./sample-script 
this will be printed
but errexit is enabled so this will not be printed
```

There is no magical juju happening, or anything terribly bizarre that is causing this behavior.  This is simply the normal behavior of the shell.  On the other hand, if we change the script slightly and make the desired behavior explicit, the unexpected behavior goes away.  Consider:

```
$ cat sample-script-2 
#!/bin/bash -e
if
echo this will be printed
false || exit
echo but this is not printed because the author was explicit about exiting
then : ; fi
$ ./sample-script-2 
this will be printed
```

errexit was an attempt to make life easier for script writers and maintainers, but it failed.  And it continues to fail.  To borrow from python: "Explicit is better than implicit".  If you want your script to terminate if a command returns non-zero, write `cmd || exit`.  If you want your script to maybe sometimes fail when a command returns non-zero and you want to ensure that the maintainers of the script really won't know what actually happens, write `set -e; cmd`