# What does `set -o errtrace` do in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the effect of this statement in a shell script?

```
set -o errtrace
```

Comment: The intent is clearly to cause the user to turn to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) but it seems to be failing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the manual:

> errtrace
>              Same as -E.
>
> -E   If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions,
>              command substitutions, and commands executed in a sub‐
>              shell environment.  The ERR trap is normally not inher‐
>              ited in such cases.

When `errtrace` is enabled, the ERR trap is also triggered when the error (a command returning a nonzero code) occurs inside a function or a subshell.  Another way to put it is that the context of a function or a subshell does not inherit the ERR trap unless `errtrace` is enabled.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errtrace

function x {
    echo "X begins."
    false
    echo "X ends."
}

function y {
    echo "Y begins."
    false
    echo "Y ends."
}

trap 'echo "ERR trap called in ${FUNCNAME-main context}."' ERR
x
y
false
true
```

Output:

```
X begins.
ERR trap called in x.
X ends.
Y begins.
ERR trap called in y.
Y ends.
ERR trap called in main context.
```

When `errtrace` is not enabled:

```
X begins.
X ends.
Y begins.
Y ends.
ERR trap called in main context.
```