# How to handle SIGKILL in bash script used tcpdump

Tags: linux, bash, tcpdump

I have a problem to pass signals like SIGKILL, SIGINT, SIGTERP to bash script which use tcpdump.

The main issue - how to kill tcpdump process (child) if homeone kill the main script.

I have the following script (part):

```sh
#for log
function log {
    echo "$CURRENT_DATE_TIME $1" >> "${LOG_DIR}/${MAIN_LOG_FILE}"
    echo "$1"
}

#to start tcpdump
function start_tcpdump {
    ${TCPDUMP} ${TCPDUMP_ARGS} ${TCPDUMP_LOG_FILE} ${TCPDUMP_SMPP_PDU} &
    TCPDUMP_PID=$!
    log "Start tcpdump PID: ${TCPDUMP_PID}"
    sleep 60

}

#to stop tcpdump
function stop_tcpdump {
    kill -s 2 ${TCPDUMP_PID}
    log "Stop tcpdump PID ${TCPDUMP_PID}"
    TCPDUMP_PID=0
}

#check if process exists
function check_tcpdump {
        if [[ ${TCPDUMP_PID} -ne 0 ]] && [[ -e /proc/${TCPDUMP_PID} ]] && kill -s 0 "${TCPDUMP_PID}" 2>/dev/null
        then
            log "Checking tcpdump. Already started PID ${TCPDUMP_PID}"
            return 1
        else
            log "Checking tcpdump. Not started"
            return 0
        fi
#       [[ ${TCPDUMP_PID} -ne 0 ]] && [[ -e /proc/${TCPDUMP_PID} ]] && kill -s 0 "${TCPDUMP_PID}" 2>/dev/null
}

#main function here
function main {
    log "#####INIT#####"
    start_tcpdump

    trap stop_tcpdump SIGINT SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGSTOP
    check_tcpdump
    stop_tcpdump
}

main
```

But if someone forget and kill sript:

```
$ sh ./gms_trace_smpp.sh

$ kill $pid
```

process which manage tcp dump still exists.

I'd like to call stop_tcpdump function and kill child tcpdump process if script gets one of the signals (SIGINT SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGSTOP).

And have made it using trap:

```
trap stop_tcpdump SIGINT SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGSTOP
```

But it doesn't work.

Does someone have any idea how to handle signal and kill child process (tcpdump) when someone kill the main script?

Comment: From `man trap` "Implementations may permit names with the SIG prefix" - but they may not. Remove the SIG prefixes from trap specification. | If you want to exit after receiving the signal, call `exit` in the trap handler.

Comment: You should have a look at [What does `set -o errtrace` do in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25378845/5291015)

Comment: SIGKILL and SIGSTOP can't be trapped!

Comment: If SIGKILL and SIGSTOP can't be trapped, how can I also stop tcpdump process in script if someone kill this script? Maybe you have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Some signals cannot normally be blocked. While there are ways to make a process unkillable, it's tricky, a bad idea, and probably not helpful.

One simple option is to add an `at` job to perform cleanup if it detects the script has exited (or it could always do the `check_tcpdump` and `stop_tcpdump` parts).

Another more complicated option is to intertwine the script with another - they can monitor each other and perform cleanup when either one exits (cf. [Robin Hood and Friar Tuck](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~elb/folklore/xerox.txt))