# Propagate python script exit code to calling shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have the following in a python script (using python 3.4), if there is any failure:

```
exit(1)
```

The purpose of this python script is to `print()` some value, so that it may be assigned to a shell variable like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
result=$(python my-script.py)
echo $?
```

However, if the script fails, the `echo` above returns 0. I want `set -e` to immediately interrupt and fail the script if the python script fails (i.e. returns non zero exit code).

How can I make this work? I tried `set -eo pipefail` as well in my bash script and I've noticed no difference.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.

### EDIT

My python script (verbatim) just in case it is the suspect here...

```
import re
import sys

version_regex = r'(?:(?:release|hotfix)\/|^)([\d.]+)-\d+-g[a-f\d]+$'

result = re.search(version_regex, sys.argv[1])
if not result:
    exit(1)

print(result.group(1))
```

Note that I have tried both `sys.exit(1)` and `exit(1)` in my experiments but I never saw my bash script fail.

### EDIT 2

```
parsed_version=$(python parse-git-describe.py $describe_result; echo $?)
echo $parsed_version
echo $?
```

The above bash script gives me the following output:

```
1
0
```

Note that the script `parse-git-describe.py` is the same as the python script provided earlier.

### EDIT 3

Apparently `local` causes this to break. EDIT 2 above was wrong, that is the result with `local` inside a shell function:

```
foo()
{
    local parsed_version=$(python parse-git-describe.py $describe_result; echo $?)
    echo $parsed_version
    echo $?
}
```

Result is:

```
1
0
```

But if I remove `local` it works fine?

```
foo()
{
    parsed_version=$(python parse-git-describe.py $describe_result; echo $?)
    echo $parsed_version
    echo $?
}
```

Result is:

```
1
1
```

Why does `local` matter?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script) SO post. Mentions `set -e` as unreliable and bad practice. Your script may not necessarily reach the `echo`

Comment: Since you're using `exit` directly, try changing your import to `from sys import exit`.

Comment: I already read that post, and I know people suggest `trap`, but I'm not sure how to use it in my specific case.

Comment: @ray my understanding of `sys.exit()` in python is that it is intended for "applications", whereas `exit()` is for interactive shell (which is my case)

Comment: Your script terminates with `local: can only be used in a function` for me.

Comment: I removed `local`, it was a bad copy/paste from my script.

Comment: @void.pointer: Based on your shell script example, you don't appear to be using the interactive *python* shell.

Comment: @ray Can you clarify? I do not know what you mean.

Comment: @void.pointer: `$ python -c 'from sys import exit; exit(1)'; echo $?` works fine for me, printing 1. Consider a simple test with simpler scripts to *reproduce* and isolate the issue. (Also on Ubuntu 15, BTW.) Did you check the post I linked to regarding `set -e`? Consider getting the return code and performing an if-check in your bash script and exit directly instead of relying on `set -e`.

Comment: Made a 3rd edit. Seems that `local` causes different behavior, I don't understand that at all.

Comment: @void.pointer: See my post regarding your question on `local`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92316/discussion-between-ray-and-void-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You can to set the exit code if you finish your script by calling [`sys.exit(code)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: I do this already though... I will update my post with the python script verbatim

Comment: You're using the built-in `exit`. Change your `exit(1)` to `sys.exit(1)` or do as @ray mentioned and add `from sys import exit` to the top of your script.

Comment: Why does it matter? I've read that both exit calls eventually call the same thing anyway. I tried them both in my experiments and I have not noticed a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `local` can only be used within a function in bash. (So your bash script code above doesn't work either.)

Why don't you call your python script in the bash script and check the return value and then jump out of your script if necessary?

```
$ python -c "exit(0)"
$ [ $? == 0 ] || echo "fail"
$ python -c "exit(1)"
$ [ $? == 0 ] || echo "fail"
fail
```

You can easily adapt this in your shell script, I guess.

Comment: Actually my bash code was a copy & paste from a function, I pieced it together for my question here. Small oversight, I will correct it. I'm not actually using `local` outside of a function in my real script thought.

Comment: A much better and more idiomatic approach would be `python -c 'exit(1)' || echo "fail"`

Comment: I'd recommend to pass on the error codes to the calling function also in your bash script and then slip out of the script according to it.

Comment: @tripleee I just wanted to make it more visible for the questioner how to pass a return value to the calling bash script...

Comment: @ferdy My bash script as I wrote it in my question is essentially testing for the same thing. My echo call returns 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `local` matter??

The `local` keyword specifies the variable's *scope*. The following sample script should illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
HELLO=Hello    # global variable, HELLO

function hello {
    local HELLO=World   # local variable with same name; diff scope
    echo $HELLO         # this is the local, not global!
}

echo $HELLO  # print global
hello        # function call!
echo $HELLO  # global unchanged!
```

Running this code from the shell (placed in `test.sh` script) produces:

```
➜  Projects  ./test.sh
Hello
World
Hello
```

When you use `local`, the variable and the exit code it had go out of scope when the function returns to the caller. Your function should return the value to the caller if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Again you're still missing my point. See the example I put here. Notice that the `local` keyword changes the behavior of being able to detect exit code. http://goo.gl/1J4IB1