# Variable assignment exits shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have simple shell script that tries to find out if a specific docker container is running. In the shell script I have the follwoing line;

```
RUNNING_CONTAINERS=$(docker ps -a | grep ${IMAGE_NAME})
```

If the grep returns no results, the shell script exits right there. How would I write my script to make sure the script continues to execute even if the result of the grep is empty?

Comment: This is probably because you have [`set -e`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19622569) somewhere in the script, and `grep` not returning any result exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: Yes I have. Make an answer and explain why it matters and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this is the existence of `set -e` somewhere in the code, which makes your script exit as soon as a command returns a non-zero status. In this case, `grep` because it did not find any match.

As read in [The Bash reference manual -> The `set` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

> ```
> -e
> ```
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a
>   single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a
>   compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status.
>   The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
>   command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of
>   the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or
>   || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command
>   in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being
>   inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a
>   non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored,
>   the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the
>   shell exits.

Also, from `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines
>   were selected, and 2 if an error  occurred. However, if the -q or
>   --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

So `grep` doesn't find anything and returns a non-zero exit status. Then, `set -e` captures it and sees it does not come from an "exception" (`if`, `while`... as mentioned in the reference), neither it is before the last command in the pipeline, so it exits.

#### Test

Let's create a very basic script:

```
$ cat a.sh 
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo "hello"
grep "hello" a
echo "bye"
```

And generate an empty `a` file:

```
$ touch a
```

If we run it we see it exits when `grep` doesn't return any result:

```
$ ./a.sh 
hello
```

However, if we remove the `set -e` line, it goes through to the end of the file:

```
$ ./a.sh 
hello
bye
```

See also it doesn't fail if `grep` is not the last element in the pipeline:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo "hello"
grep "hello" a | echo "he"
echo "bye"
$ ./a.sh 
hello
he
bye
```