# How to automate mysql_secure_installation in Chef

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Chef mysql recipe- in-order to setup a permanent password for root user in mysql, I did find a process which uses "bash" resource in recipe for running a bash script which automates all the steps which pop-up in the process. But after running the convergence it errors out

> "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

I understand it is because initially the temporary password is generated in mysqld.log files and I need to provide this temp passwd for running the mysql_secure_installation. But I couldn't find a way to include a step in the script where it can bring this temp passwd from the logs and use it in the script. Below is the script I'm currently running in the recipe.

```
root_password = node.set['mysql_user']['root']['password']
bash "mysql_secure_installation" do
  code <<-EOH
    mysql -u root -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';"
    mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE test;"
    mysql -u root -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';"
    mysql -u root -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');"
    mysql -u root -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('#{root_password}');" -D mysql
    mysql -u root -p#{root_password} -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('#{root_password}');" -D mysql
    mysql -u root -p#{root_password} -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('#{root_password}');" -D mysql
    mysql -u root -p#{root_password} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
  EOH
end
```

Comment: What `mysql` cookbook version and `mysql_server` resource are you using to install the MySQL server? AFAIK in the latest version of the cookbook you should use `initial_root_password` to set the root password.

Comment: I'm not using mysql community cookbook. I developed my custom cookbook based on the regular installation process on centos 6.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your script will only work on the first convergence.

Second, your `bash` resource will only return the error of the last command (*FLUSH PRIVILEGES*). The other command errors will be ignored by the resource and the chef execution will continue. You need to use [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script) or add a `&&` between mysql commands to avoid this.

Anyway, I very much recommend you to try to use the official [`mysql`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql) cookbook for your task. It will make it simpler. You can use something like the following to install and set the root password:

```ruby
mysql_service 'default' do
  port '3306'
  initial_root_password root_password
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

Keep in mind that this cookbook [already takes many of your security measures](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/blob/v6.1.3/libraries/helpers.rb#L170-L175) out of the box:

```mysql
UPDATE mysql.user SET #{password_column_name}=PASSWORD('#{root_password}')#{password_expired} WHERE user = 'root';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE USER LIKE '';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root' and host NOT IN ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%';
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;
```

After that, you can also run your own SQL scripts using [`database`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/database) and [`mysql2_chef_gem`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql2_chef_gem) cookbooks if you want:

```ruby
# Required by `database` cookbook MySQL resources:
mysql2_chef_gem 'default'

connection_info = {
  :host     => '127.0.0.1',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => root_password
}

mysql_database 'mysql_secure_installation' do
  connection connection_info
  database_name 'mysql'
  sql <<-EOH
    -- MY MYSQL SCRIPT HERE;
  EOH
  action :query
end
```