# What does 'set -e' and 'set -a' do in Bash? What are other options that I can use with the 'set' command?

Tags: manpage

I would like to know as what do the below commands do in Bash.

- `set -e`
- `set -a`

Comment: i found set -e  means exit on non zero status. Now need to know meaning of -a option.

Comment: Half duplicated of [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19622198/1983854).

Comment: `man set` and `help set` work for me on Debian/jessie64.

Comment: `man set` worked on one of my Jessie machines,but not on another.  I checked, and found that the man page is in the (optional) `manpages-posix` package.  `help set` is of course a Bash builtin, so always available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> -a Mark variables and function which are modified or created for export to the environment of subsequent commands
>
> -e Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists),
>   or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero
>   status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of
>   the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part
>   of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a &&
>   or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any
>   command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status
>   is being inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell
>   returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being
>   ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>   before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell
>   environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may
>   cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
>   subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e
>   is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound
>   command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if
>   -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where
>   -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call
>   completes.

Comment: updated docs have better explanation: :-a
Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands."

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 20):

Try running:

```
help set
```

Output is:

```
set: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
    Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.

    Change the value of shell attributes and positional parameters, or
    display the names and values of shell variables.

    Options:
      -a  Mark variables which are modified or created for export.
      -b  Notify of job termination immediately.
      -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
      -f  Disable file name generation (globbing).
      -h  Remember the location of commands as they are looked up.
      -k  All assignment arguments are placed in the environment for a
          command, not just those that precede the command name.
      -m  Job control is enabled.
      -n  Read commands but do not execute them.
      -o option-name
          Set the variable corresponding to option-name:
              allexport    same as -a
              braceexpand  same as -B
              emacs        use an emacs-style line editing interface
              errexit      same as -e
              errtrace     same as -E
              functrace    same as -T
              hashall      same as -h
              histexpand   same as -H
              history      enable command history
              ignoreeof    the shell will not exit upon reading EOF
              interactive-comments
                           allow comments to appear in interactive commands
              keyword      same as -k
              monitor      same as -m
              noclobber    same as -C
              noexec       same as -n
              noglob       same as -f
              nolog        currently accepted but ignored
              notify       same as -b
              nounset      same as -u
              onecmd       same as -t
              physical     same as -P
              pipefail     the return value of a pipeline is the status of
                           the last command to exit with a non-zero status,
                           or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status
              posix        change the behavior of bash where the default
                           operation differs from the Posix standard to
                           match the standard
              privileged   same as -p
              verbose      same as -v
              vi           use a vi-style line editing interface
              xtrace       same as -x
      -p  Turned on whenever the real and effective user ids do not match.
          Disables processing of the $ENV file and importing of shell
          functions.  Turning this option off causes the effective uid and
          gid to be set to the real uid and gid.
      -t  Exit after reading and executing one command.
      -u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.
      -v  Print shell input lines as they are read.
      -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
      -B  the shell will perform brace expansion
      -C  If set, disallow existing regular files to be overwritten
          by redirection of output.
      -E  If set, the ERR trap is inherited by shell functions.
      -H  Enable ! style history substitution.  This flag is on
          by default when the shell is interactive.
      -P  If set, do not resolve symbolic links when executing commands
          such as cd which change the current directory.
      -T  If set, the DEBUG trap is inherited by shell functions.
      --  Assign any remaining arguments to the positional parameters.
          If there are no remaining arguments, the positional parameters
          are unset.
      -   Assign any remaining arguments to the positional parameters.
          The -x and -v options are turned off.

    Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.  The
    flags can also be used upon invocation of the shell.  The current
    set of flags may be found in $-.  The remaining n ARGs are positional
    parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, .. $n.  If no
    ARGs are given, all shell variables are printed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given.
```

Comment: For an actual explanation, see e.g.  *[What does 'set -e' mean in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script/38798777#38798777)*.

Comment: [An exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script/73672675#73672675) is an `if` statement.