# Post install script: OpenSSH fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openssh

I am currently working on a post install script for servers (mostly for myself, since I know what I need/want), targeting debian 8.

But I have issues by make OpenSSH.

First of all:

Variables:

```
OPENSSL_VERSION="1.1.0e"
OPENSSH_VERSION="7.4p1"
```

And that is the rest of the scripts:

```
# OpenSSL
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --force-yes install openssl/unstable libssl-dev/unstable
cd /tmp
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz
wget https://ftp.spline.de/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssh-${OPENSSH_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd openssh-${OPENSSH_VERSION}

./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pam --with-zlib --with-ssl-engine --with-ssl-dir=/etc/ssl --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
make && mv /etc/ssh{,.bak} && make install

sed -i 's/^#Port 22/Port 2211/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#AddressFamily any/AddressFamily inet/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#Protocol 2/Protocol 2/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ed25519_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ed25519_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#ServerKeyBits 1024/ServerKeyBits 2048/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#RekeyLimit default none/RekeyLimit 256M/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#LogLevel INFO/LogLevel VERBOSE/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h/KeyRegenerationInterval 1800/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#SyslogFacility AUTH/SyslogFacility AUTH/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#LoginGraceTime 2m/LoginGraceTime 30/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#MaxAuthTries 6/MaxAuthTries 20/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#StrictModes yes/StrictModes yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#RSAAuthentication yes/RSAAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#PubkeyAuthentication yes/PubkeyAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^AuthorizedKeysFile   .ssh\/authorized_keys/#AuthorizedKeysFile   .ssh\/authorized_keys/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#RhostsRSAAuthentication no/RhostsRSAAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#HostbasedAuthentication no/HostbasedAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#PermitEmptyPasswords no/PermitEmptyPasswords no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes/ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#AllowTcpForwarding yes/AllowTcpForwarding yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#X11Forwarding no/X11Forwarding yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#X11DisplayOffset 10/X11DisplayOffset 10/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#PrintMotd yes/PrintMotd no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#PrintLastLog yes/PrintLastLog yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#TCPKeepAlive yes/TCPKeepAlive yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#UsePAM no/UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/issue/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#MaxStartups 10:30:100/MaxStartups 2/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^#MaxSessions 10/MaxSessions 3/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/^Subsystem    sftp    \/usr\/libexec\/sftp-server/Subsystem sftp \/usr\/lib\/openssh\/sftp-server/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "# Allow client to pass locale environment variables" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "AcceptEnv LANG LC_* TZ" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "# KEX algorithms">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "# Ciphers">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "# MAC algorithms">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,umac-128@openssh.com">> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The issue starts at this:

```
make && mv /etc/ssh{,.bak} && make install
```

When I try to make, I am getting this error:

```
make: *** [sshkey.o] Error 1
```

Also I assume when make fails, every command after it won't be executed, or?

Because

```
mv /etc/ssh{,.bak}
```

Isn't working either, aswell as all the sed commands. I am basically ending up with the default OpenSSH install AND configuration - /etc/ssh/sshd_config remains default after this.

PS: Packages and libs:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude -y install apt-listchanges arj autoconf automake bison bsd-mailx build-essential bzip2 cmake ca-certificates cabextract checkinstall curl dnsutils file flex git htop libapr1-dev libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dev libauthen-sasl-perl-Daemon libawl-php libcunit1-dev libcrypt-ssleay-perl libcurl4-openssl-dev libdbi-perl libgeoip-dev libio-socket-ssl-perl libio-string-perl liblockfile-simple-perl liblogger-syslog-perl libmail-dkim-perl libmail-spf-perl libmime-base64-urlsafe-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-ident-perl libnet-LDAP-perl libnet1 libnet1-dev libpam-dev libpcre-ocaml-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libreadline6-dev libtest-tempdir-perl libtool libuv-dev libwww-perl libxml2 libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxslt1-dev libyaml-dev lzop mariadb-server memcached mlocate netcat nettle-dev nomarch pkg-config python-setuptools python-software-properties rkhunter software-properties-common subversion sudo unzip zip zlib1g-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dbg zlib1g-de zoo
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Make failed for some reason. The reason is certainly written in the log. Without attaching it, nobody around here can know what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only want to run `make`, if `configure` was successful.

`./configure <flags> && make && make install`

Also you could use `set e` to [exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622569/831651), since for example, you don't want to continue, if `wget` fails, etc.