# PHP cURL Access Fails to Remote Docker Hub/Registry

Tags: php, curl, docker, docker-registry

In order to facilitate a remote CICD process for our applications I am trying to access our Docker Hub/Registry to be able to list, tag and push images. Starting with [the basics](https://success.docker.com/Cloud/Solve/How_do_I_authenticate_with_the_V2_API%3F) using the following from a bash script:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${UNAME}'", "password": "'${UPASS}'"}' https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)
```

I created some cURL in PHP, trying to get a token for Docker Hub:

```
$user = 'xxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxx';
$namespace = 'xxxxxxxx';
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$url = "https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($return);
```

**The response:**

> bool(false)

If I enter the URL https://regsitry.hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ directly into the address bar of the browser I get:

```
{"username": ["This field is required."], "password": ["This field is required."]}
```

If I eliminate the username and password from the cURL request I still get the `bool(false)` response. There is very little (*actually I found next to nothing*) for using PHP to interact with the Docker Hub/Registry API(s). There are no errors in my error logs.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is there no way to interact with the Docker API via PHP?

Comment: Hi i guess set -e is a pipeline and stops the execution of a script if a command or pipeline has an error but with curl in PHP the pipeline isn't garanted as a lot bug reported about this option on CURL but take a look if you can add this CURLMOPT_PIPELINING no sure of the result.

Comment: Why did you turn the JSON auth payload into HTTP auth?

Comment: `set -e` is for environment variables @headmax

Comment: As @Sammitch posted the answer, what you are trying is for sites with Basic Auth and not for a JSON payload.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Yes and set -e is using to send the credentials on the shell pipeline you can to set -o pipefail which can be used to propagate errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
```

is not equivalent to:

```
-d '{"username": "'${UNAME}'", "password": "'${UPASS}'"}'
```

but this is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['username'=>$user, 'password'=>$pass]));
```

and it works.

Comment: Please ignore the last comment - I made a typo. Thanks for the insight @sammitch!