# Can Bamboo detect failure based on JSON response of Curl Request?

Tags: curl, bamboo

I have a Curl post request defined in a shell script as part of a task in my default job in a Bamboo plan.

The Curl request performs a deployment on one of my QA environments. It takes about 2 hours for finish the deployment as its a full stack deployment.

Once the deployment is done, to check the status of the deployment, I wish to send one more curl request whose response has a status field which says if its a successful deployment or not.

Here is the sample response from the request:

```
{
  "_id" : "xxx",
  "templateId" : "xxx",
  "templateName" : "all full reinstall",
  "epoch" : "2021-11-12T10:22:14.268Z",
  "userEmail" : "xxx@xxx.com",
  "playbook" : "all_full_reinstall.yml",
  "repoId" : "xxx",
  "repoName" : "tower-in-house",
  "inventoryId" : "xxx",
  "inventoryName" : "xxx",
  "status" : "failed"
}
```

I have other stages that trigger some regression tests but these should trigger only if the status is success and not failed.

The challenge is the curl request gives a response of 200. But within the response I wish to read the field of 'status' to decide if the stage is successful or not.

I looked at [Can Bamboo interpret an HTTP 400 Bad request as a failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052081/can-bamboo-interpret-an-http-400-bad-request-as-a-failure) but this talks about returning non 2xx codes. In my case it returns a 200 but one of the json response fields contains the error message that I need to look to decide if its a failure or success.

Is there a way I can proceed? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Oleksiy Chystoprudov's answer above and I was able to resolve this.

This is what I used

```
response=$(curl -s "API_Endpoint_to_check_deployment_status" | jq '.status' | tr -d '"' )
if [ "$response" = "success" ]; then
exit 0
else
exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can craft shell script which will analyse response JSON with some library like jq and then call exit 0 or exit 1 depending on status field value.
In case of exit 1 Bamboo will mark task and job as failed

Comment: thank you very much for this idea. I shall try it and let you know.