# How to check whether a partition exists with hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-partitions

I have a HiveQL script that can do some operations based on a hive table. But before doing these operations, I will check whether the partition needed exists, and if not, I will terminate the script. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: If you use Hive why is it marked as [apache-spark]?

Answer (score 2):

Using shell:

```
table_name="schema.table"
partition_spec="key=value"

partition_exists=$(hive -e "show partitions $table_name" | grep "$partition_spec");

#check partition_exists
 if [ "$partition_exists" = "" ]; then echo not exists; else echo exists; fi
```

Comment: just a side note.   If above is put in a shell script, and this shell script is called via another script (say called parent.sh), then the parent.sh should not have "set -e" condition, otherwise the "echo not exists will not will be executed..... reason, the sub shell partition_exists actually return non zero code if the partition does not exist

Comment: instead of removing the set -e, it can be done like this (sorry, i could not edit the above comment after certain time): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612582/4582240