# How to check if a partition exists in Hive?

Tags: java, hive, hive-metastore

I have a Hive table, which is partitioned by column `dt`. I need to add a partition if it does not exists, for exmaple, `dt='20181219'`.

Now I'm using `HiveMetaStoreClient#getPartition(dbName, tableName, 20181219)`. If  the partition does not exists, then catch `NoSuchObjectException` and add it.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174062/2700344

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `add_partition(Partition, ifNotExists, needResults)` ([javadoc](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html#add_partitions-java.util.List-boolean-boolean-)) ... which (if the 2nd argument is `true`) will only create an partition if it doesn't already exist.

Alternatively, just use `add_partition(Partition)` to add the partition *without a test*, and catch the `AlreadyExistsException` if it occurs.

---

Any scheme that involves testing that an action is possible and then doing that action has a potential race condition.  In between the "test" and the "do", some other agent (thread, client, whatever) could do an action (the same one or a different one) that will cause your attempt to fail.

So your current approach is not only ugly.  It also has a potential race condition if partitions could be created by multiple agents.