# Python/Shell script to alert missing hive partition

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, python-2.7, hive

Every day my job runs and load the data in Hive table, its partition by 'date' column, it represents the daily run.
If any day my job fails to create a new partition column (2022-01-03) it should alert me via email. Can anyone give a solution to this problem?

show partitions mytable;

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-04
```

if I run the script, it makes sure the current date(2022-01-24) is present in HDFS path, if not it alerts a message missing to email id

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804773/alert-the-hive-missing-partition. If you want help, please provide more information about the job - is it a python script? Or a PowerShell script? Or a simple bash script? Either way, please _post the current script_ if you want help adding error handling to it :)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174062/2700344