# Diff command stops the execution of the shell-script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, diff

I'm creating a script to compare two directories:

```
    for qa_branch in $QA_BRANCHES
    do
        exist_px=false
        info "1qa: $qa_branch"

        for px_branch in $PX_BRANCHES
        do
            info "2px: $px_branch"
            if [ "$qa_branch" = "$px_branch" ]; then
                exist_px=true

                cd test1
                checkout_branch "$qa_branch" || error "branch does not exist"
                cd ..

                cd test2    
                checkout_branch "$px_branch" || error "branch does not exist"
                cd ..

                echo
                info "compare_branches QA: $qa_branch with PX: $px_branch"
                diff -r --exclude=".*" test1/  test2/ 
                info "########################################################################"
            fi
        done
        info $exist_px
        echo
    done
```

When the execution reaches the **diff** command it stops and the execution of the script does not continue. How can i fix this?

The idea is to capture the differences and send them by email.

Thank you!

Comment: "Stops" as in taking a long time? Obviously comparing a lot of identical files will take time and not produce any output.

Comment: The execution directly ends in the first comparison and the last line (info "#############...) is not printed.

Comment: So the script exits and you are back at the prompt? Or it hangs but you are somehow sure it's not still comparing something?

Comment: Exactly, the script exits and I'm back at the prompt.

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in the parts you are not showing?

Comment: I have this configuration: `set -o errexit
set -o nounset`

Comment: That's why it exits then, probably even bofore running `diff`. With `errexit` aka `set -e` you have to understand and handle the return status from every single command you run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem!