# Loop shell script is being killed when kill child

Tags: linux, shell

```
#! /bin/sh -e
cd /home/pi/projects/3._Raspberry_Client/bin/ARM/Debug
while true;
do
  ./3._Raspberry_Client.out
  sleep 3s
done
```

I want to start program when it be killed.

So, I make shell script; like sample.

If Run it on bash and do `kill -9 something`, it perfectly works.

But I want to run this shell script on startup.

I set it in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

like,

```
./Client_Boot.sh (this is in /home/pi)
```

then I reboot, shell script works.

But If I kill the program, shell script is also being killed too.

Why this happens? And What should I do?

Thanks for your kindness. And Sry to Bad English.

Comment: `/bin/sh -e` - read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script Does your application exit with non zero status when receiving a signal?

Comment: Does it mean, need to add 'set -e' and check my status code?

Comment: `/bin/sh -e` - the `-e` is already in there, replace `/bin/sh -e` with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: My GODNESS! It works very well. Thanks a lot. It's VERY helpful :)