# Force Airflow to terminate with exit code 1

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Some of the tasks I run in Airflow occasionally fail for various reasons. Some I catch and others are new and aren't excepted. I want to get exit code 1 in order to receive a notification of such failures.

Below is an example of an error I didn't except, is there a way to have ValueError yield exit code 1?

```
[2019-06-13 12:56:13,630] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - ValueError: year 43631 is out of range
[2019-06-13 12:56:13,870] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - 2019-06-13 12:56:13,869 - ODL - INFO - Closing db connection
[2019-06-13 12:56:13,870] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - 2019-06-13 12:56:13,870 - ODL - INFO - End
[2019-06-13 12:56:13,990] {bash_operator.py:131} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2019-06-13 12:56:17,556] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-06-13 12:56:17,555] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

I also have other bits of code where the try block uses `sys.exit(1)`. However, it is not raised, do I need to raise this error in order to exit with 1?

I've tried using sys.exit(1) in my try blocks.

```
        if count==0:
            self._logger.error("Missing data, nothing was loaded")
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            self._logger.info("Data is present, safe to load to prod!")
```

I expected to get the following in order to be notified of the failure.

```
2019-06-13 12:56:17,556] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-06-13 12:56:17,555] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `BashOperator` to call your Python script. This means you'll want to use something like `set -e` to ensure Bash stops execution when it hits the non-zero code on your Python command and it exits itself with the same code, see [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script) for more details. Then this should fail the task as you'd expect.