# What's the equivalent of 'set -e' (exit on any errors) in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've been using Unix for about 20 years, but only started using Powershell recently. I have a `ps1` script that does a number of tasks.

I know I *could* check each of them, and throw if they error, but it would be good for the entire script just to exit on any errors - [like `set -e` does in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script).

**How can I make a Powershell script exit immediately upon any error?**

Using pwsh 6.2.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having just found the answer to my own question:

[`ErrorActionPreference`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-erroractionpreference-to-control-cmdlet-handling-of-errors/) does this.

```
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
```

at the top of the `ps1` file.

Comment: You can also use "-ErrorAction Stop" if you want it to stop on certain commands, rather than the whole script.

Comment: Note that this applies to PowerShell commands only; `$ErrorActionPreference` has no effect on calls to _external programs_ reporting failure via `$LASTEXITCODE`. [This RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/88/files) aims to introduce an abort-on-failure mechanism for external programs too.

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference` doesn't work (at least, for external commands). Please see [this](/a/57949447) and [this](/a/48877892) amazing answers.