# Using diff in a dedicated function causes the calling script to hang on first file comparison

Tags: bash, diff, io-redirection

For some reason after running the main script:

`sudo bash main.sh`

-> execution stops at the first diff redirected to file.

However, when I comment out the function name and parentheses and call the `patching.sh` directly - it works.

What is wrong with my script that when calling it in a form of a function from another file - it stops, but when called directly it works?

main.sh:

```
set -e
source $(dirname $0)/Scripts/patching.sh
# Overwrite files 
update_files
```

patching.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function update_files() {

    declare -r SW_DIR='Source/packages/'

    CMP_FILE='file1.c'
    diff -u ./$SW_DIR/examples/$CMP_FILE ./Source/$CMP_FILE > file.diff
    cp -v ./Source/$CMP_FILE ./$SW_DIR/examples/$CMP_FILE

}
```

During my debugging - I added the `-x` option to `set`. This is what I see now:

```
+ declare -r SW_DIR=Source/packages
+ CMP_FILE=file1.c
+ diff -u ./Source/packages/examples/file1.c ./Source/file1.c
```

And that's the last line. If I omit the redirection operator - the diff is simply shown in the console and that's it. It does not proceed further, with **no** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script) and [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).  Execution stops after the `diff` when `set -e` is in effect because `diff` exits with non-zero status when the files that it is comparing are different.  This kind of behaviour is one of the downsides of using `set -e`.  Follow the links for more, and useful, information.