# 'OMP: Error #179' when using hugging face BERT

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, huggingface

I simply tried running this code.

```py
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer
```

with this command. For 'GPU_ID' I used my GPU UUID, which wasn't wrong.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='GPU_ID' python3 MNLI.py
```

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes this error pops up.

```
OMP: Error #179: Function Can't open SHM failed:
OMP: System error #0: Success
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't resolved it yet. However, sometimes the error occurs and sometimes it works, so I'm just running it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. To me it's strange that the message `OMP: System error #0: Success` indicates that the error `OMP: Error #179: Function Can't open SHM failed:` was resolved, but the execution still results in a core dump. Are you executing the `python3 MNLI.py` within a shell script that includes the command [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script)? That may explain this behavior.