# Catching error in a shell script when performing git checkout

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I have written a script that clones a repo, creates a new branch, performs some changes, and pushes the changes. I am unsure what will happen in case of an error during branch creation. Because if there is some failure there is a possibility that the changes can get commit to the default branch. Here is an MRE of the script:

```
while read REPO
   do
      git clone {repo-url}
      cd $REPO
      if [ -d "$REPO-test" ]; then
        git checkout -b $BRANCH
          $command  // This command makes changes to some files in the repository. It actually creates a new file
          git add $file
          git commit ...
          git push ....
      fi
    done < $REPOS
```

I thought of using the exit code to test like:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then 
  echo "Success" 
else 
  echo "Failure"
fi
```

So do this right after the `git checkout -b $BRANCH` and don't proceed further in case of error / the `else` clause.

I am not sure if that will make it error-proof or if there is a better way to achieve this in shell script or better commands to use in `git`

Comment: Just like almost all other *nix tools `git` will have a non-zero exit status whenever a command can't finish normally. So `git checkout -b $BRANCH || exit 1` would work. Or use [`set -e` (with all its caveats)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script).

Comment: That's broadly speaking the right idea, but see [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) - you want `git checkout -b blah || exit` to abort if the command fails. (Or, more broadly, explore `set -e`; but understand that this requires a whole different discipline around possible errors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: @JoachimSauer ninja'd me, but I hope my comment helps spell things out in more detail.

Comment: You could maybe look at how the shell scripts are structured in the Git project. They seem to like doing things like chaining with `&&`. [link](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69c786637d7a7fe3b2b8f7d989af095f5f49c3a8/t/t1020-subdirectory.sh)

Comment: I would test for the success of the checkout by doing `if git checkout -b $BRANCH; then ...`. And if you run bash (you tagged the question with both _bash_ and _zsh_, which is a bad idea anyay), doublequote your variables if there is the possibility that they contain spaces (I don't know whether spaces are allowed in git branch names, but `file` most likely **can** contain a space).

Comment: Do not `echo success` or `echo failure`.  (If you do `echo failure`, make sure you do `echo failure >&2`, but don't do either).  Let the command emit the error message.  Just do `cmd || exit 1`, or `git add "$file" && git commit ... && git push ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then echo "Success"; else echo "Failure"; fi
```

after each command or `git` will give you an overview of what went wrong (or right). It will not stop you from executing the rest of the commands.

The problem with using `$?` is, that you must make sure that the last command is really always the `git`. That may seem trivial, but when others  maintain your script, or you need to change something after a year, it is a cause of errors.

In general, I would

```
if git add "$file" ; then
    echo "Added $file to git"
else
    # do some repair actions or bail-out with
    exit 1
fi
```

This gives you more flexibility to repair common problems than just

```
git checkout -b "$BRANCH" || exit 1
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is arguing against an explicit `if` structure if you need more complex handling of failures than one or two commands after `||`. The question doesn't reveal what exactly should happen if the `git` command fails; both constructs have their uses.

Comment: For the record, `git checkout -b blah || { echo "$0: bailing out" >&2; exit 1; }` is a reasonably common idiom if you want to use the short-circuit `||` but need more than one command there.

Comment: I have always been against one-liners, especially if the script needs to be maintained by others.

Comment: But `if command; then : nothing; else exit; fi` is a _lot_ clunkier than `command || exit` for correctly returning the failure exit code from `command` to the caller. You have to understand both idioms anyway.