# Shell one liner custom curl command with if else handling

Tags: python, linux, shell, curl, command

I'm trying to read a url using **curl** command, and expecting command to exit with return code 0 or 1 based on response of curl after parsing the response json.

I tried to parse a json response, but notable to make it working in if else condition.

*URL - localhost:8080/health*

response of the url

```
{
    "db": {
        "status": "healthy"
    },
    "scheduler": {
        "fetch": "2024-03-12T04:32:53.060917+00:00",
        "status": "healthy"
    }
}
```

**Expected output -**
**one liner cmd to return with exit code 0 if scheduler.status is healthy else 1**

Note - I'm not looking for curl response as 0 or 1 but looking for command to exit with 0 or 1.

Purpose - If my scheduler status is unhealthy than my process would terminate and exit from the app.

I'm able to parse the response message but notable to apply condition properly on response here is what i tried so far,

**cmd 1 :**

```
if ((status=$(curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' | python -c "import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin) ['scheduler'] ['status'])"))='healthy'); then exit 0; else 1;
```

It throws error as.

```
zsh: parse error near `='healthy''
```

From above cmd this `curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' | python -c "import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin) ['scheduler'] ['status'])"` part is working fine returns (healthy/unhealthy) while adding condition failing.

**cmd 2:**

```
/bin/sh -c "status=$(curl -kf https://localhost:8080/health --no- progress-meter | grep -Eo "scheduler [^}]" | grep -Eo '[^{]$' | grep -Eo "status [^}]" | grep -Eo "[^:]$" | tr -d \"' | tr -d '\r' | tr -d '\ '); if [ $status=='unhealthy']; then exit 1; fi;0"
```

This is also not working but, this part `curl -kf https://localhost:8080/health --no- progress-meter | grep -Eo "scheduler [^}]" | grep -Eo '[^{]$' | grep -Eo "status [^}]" | grep -Eo "[^:]$" | tr -d \"' | tr -d '\r' | tr -d '\ '` is working fine to return healthy/unhealthy

I tried all this short of, but no luck not sure if there is any workaround with a single cmd.

great if there is any option using shell without python else with python would also work

**Please note - No Jq or any other tool installation is required, just with existing commands**

Comment: could you install jq ?  to avoid python and other tools or parsing json data

Comment: `/bin/sh` means you don't have `pipefail` support available, _or_ the PIPESTATUS array. It's really not capable enough for quality logic here.

Comment: BTW, the use of `(( ))` is why zsh is trying to parse content as numeric (and thus failing as you show); I'm not sure why you're writing code using that construct here.

Comment: Thanks @Mate, but can't install jq or any other tool,

Comment: ...assuming your `curl | python` code works, you can use `if [ "$(curl ... | python ...)" = healthy ]; then` and there you are; no `(( ))` called for.

Comment: (`[ $status=='unhealthy']` is also broken several different ways; sh isn't guaranteed to support `==`, and spaces are needed around a comparison operator and before the `]` argument, and one needs to quote expansions to prevent them from being subject to globbing or word-splitting in any POSIX-compliant shell; `[ "$status" = healthy ]` is fine, though I'm not going to speak to all the outer quoting/wrapping).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, for your response. i tried comparing with `=`  and in double quotes also but no luck.

Comment: already tried `if [ "$(curl ... | python ...)" = healthy ]; then` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know you don't have a '}' in your health variables, you can use

```
curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' | tr -d '\n' | grep -Eq '"scheduler": [^}]*"healthy"'
```

Comment: Thanks @Walter couple of answer were working as i expected , but your answer short very short and liner .

Answer (score 1):

if you could install jq  ( https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ )

```
response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health")
status=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.scheduler.status')

if [ "$status" = "healthy" ]; then
    echo "Scheduler is healthy."
else
    echo "Scheduler is not healthy."
    exit 1
fi
```

with python

```
response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health"); python -c "import sys, json; print('Scheduler is healthy' if json.loads(sys.argv[1])['scheduler']['status'] == 'healthy' else 'Scheduler is not healthy')" "$response"
```

https://onlinegdb.com/chz6wbRK-

using python sys.exit()

```
response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health");  python -c "import sys, json; sys.exit(0 if json.loads(sys.argv[1])['scheduler']['status'] == 'healthy' else 1)" "$response"
```

https://onlinegdb.com/3CZiYyHUQ

or bash exit 1

```
response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health");xxx=$(python3 -c "import sys, json; print(0 if json.loads(sys.argv[1])['scheduler']['status'] == 'healthy' else 1)" "$response"); if [ $xxx -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
```

Support empty reponses as errors

```
response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health");xxx=$(python3 -c "import sys, json;  print(0 if sys.argv[1] and json.loads(sys.argv[1])['scheduler']['status'] == 'healthy' else 1)" "$response"); if [ $xxx -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Rp0_jkHTv

Comment: thanks for your response, but looking for one liner command and without jq or any other tool

Comment: @subodh, "one liner" is meaningless -- replace newlines with `;`s anywhere it's syntactically permissible, and there you are. It's actively unhelpful to other users here to ask people to give you answers formatted unreadably when you can instead get an answer in easy-to-follow form and through a trivial/mechanical transform make it unreadable yourself later.

Comment: Thanks @Mate, but command always returning else condition

Comment: yes, this `response=$(curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health"); if echo "$response" | grep -q '"db":{"status":"healthy"' && echo "$response" | grep -q '"scheduler":{"status":"healthy"'; then echo "Scheduler is healthy"; else echo "Scheduler is not healthy"; fi` always executing else condition

Comment: Yes. I removed it. Thx

Comment: Thanks @Mate, for your quick response,  with python will print statement of print(..), but this will not exit the process with status as 0 or 1 , don't want response but based on response command should exit, example if statue is unhealthy than command should exit as `exit 1`

Comment: "let the genie out of the bottle"

Comment: :) Expected output - one liner cmd to return with exit code 0 if scheduler.status is healthy else 1

Comment: Thanks @Mate for your solutions, but  in case of else block, giving error as `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/ init.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Maybe health endpoint returns empty response body. We could add a basic validation and do an assumption like "empty body = error".

Comment: Thanks @Mate for your help, all yours options are working , found very short and liner answer of Walter hence accepting his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll hold that `jq` is the right tool for the job, and the presented `awk` solution is quite brittle ...

```
$status=$(curl -kf https://localhost:8080/health --no- progress-meter | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n    \"";FS="\n"}$1~/scheduler/&&$3!~/healthy/{exit 1}')
```

Comment: me too, but he wrote: `Please note - No Jq or any other tool installation is required, just with existing commands`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't get hung-up on a "one-liner", though it can be done. Sometimes it's more important to get the job done, and then make sure someone (possibly you) can read and understand and *safely edit to maintain* it in six or twenty months...

That said -

```
$: json=$(curl "@{args[@]}")
$: echo "$json"
{
    "db": {
        "status": "healthy"
    },
    "scheduler": {
        "fetch": "2024-03-12T04:32:53.060917+00:00",
        "status": "healthy"
    }
}
$: echo "$json" | sed -En '
 /"scheduler"[[:space:]]*:/,/}/{
  /"status"/,/}/{
   H
   /}/{ g
        s/^.*"status"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/
        p
        q
   }
  }
 }
'
healthy
```

You could also save the JSON directly to a file -

```
$: echo "$(cat file)"
{
    "db": {
        "status": "healthy"
    },
    "scheduler": {
        "fetch": "2024-03-12T04:32:53.060917+00:00",
        "status": "healthy"
    }
}
$: if [ healthy = "$(cat file)" ]; then echo ok; else echo nope; fi
nope
$: sed -Eni '
 /"scheduler"[[:space:]]*:/,/}/{
  /"status"/,/}/{
   H
   /}/{ g
        s/^.*"status"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/
        p
        q
   }
  }
 }
' file
$: cat file
healthy
$: if [ healthy = $(cat file) ]; then echo ok; else echo nope; fi
ok
$: status=$(cat file)
$: echo $status
healthy
$: if [ healthy = "$status" ]; then echo ok; else echo nope; fi
ok
```

Personally, I *always* use `bash` if possible, and it usually is for me, with GNU versions of `awk` and `sed`, etc, so -

```
$: read -r status < <( sed -En '/"scheduler"[[:space:]]*:/,/}/{ /"status"/,/}/{H;/}/{g;s/^.*"status"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/;p}}}' <<< "$json")  
$: echo $status
healthy
$: if [[ healthy == "$status" ]] # ...
```

or something like

```
$: case $status in healthy) echo ok;; *) echo nope;; esac
ok
```

or even

```
$: case $(cat file | # or curl "${args[@]}" |
>           sed -En '/"scheduler"[[:space:]]*:/,/}/{ /"status"/,/}/{H;/}/{g;s/^.*"status"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/;p;};};}'
>        ) in healthy) echo ok;; *) echo nope;; esac
ok
```

Which means:

```
case $(curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' | python -c "import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin) ['scheduler'] ['status'])") in healthy) echo ok;; *) echo nope;; esac
```

or

```
if [[ healthy == "$(curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' |
      python -c "import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin) ['scheduler'] ['status'])"
                 )" ]]
then echo ok
fi
```

or even better:

```
isOK() { curl -s "$1" |
   python -c $'import sys, json;\nif "healthy" != json.load(sys.stdin)["scheduler"]["status"]: sys.exit(1)\n'
}
if isOK 'https://localhost:8080/health'
then : do OK stuff
else : do ERROR stuff.
fi
```

Pretty sure `zsh` exits with the last command's exit code too, so maybe all you need is

```
curl -s "https://localhost:8080/health" | python -c '
import sys, json
if "healthy" != json.load(sys.stdin)["scheduler"]["status"]: sys.exit(1)
'
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul, for your inputs it really helps , and things to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the comparison inside the Python script.

```
curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' |
  python -c 'import sys, json; sys.exit(json.load(sys.stdin)["scheduler"]["status"]) != "healthy")'; then
```

No `if` needed; if this is the last (or only) command in your script, its exit status is the exit status of the script.

Answer (score 0):

The oneliner which do the job is following:

```
curl -sS localhost:8080/health | jq -e '.scheduler.status == "healthy"' > /dev/null && exit 0 || exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, for your response, i already mentioned in the question's note `Please note - No Jq or any other tool installation is required, just with existing commands

`

Answer (score 0):

The minimal fix is to replace the numeric context with a regular Bash conditional.

```
status=$(curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' |
    python -c "import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin) ['scheduler'] ['status'])")

if [[ $status = 'healthy' ]]; then
    exit 0
else
    # also add missing exit
    exit 1
# also add missing fi
fi
```

Notice the use of `[[`...`]]` over `((`...`))`, and the use of spaces around the tokens within. (The same is true within `[`...`]` and the immediate reason your second command didn't work, either. But the repeated complex `grep` and `tr` is significantly more brittle and hard to debug than the robust JSON parser in Python.)

You haven't indicated which precise shell you are using; if it's not Bash, `if [ "$status" = 'healthy' ]` should work, too.

... Or, you could turn around and perform the comparison in Python, too:

```
curl -s 'https://localhost:8080/health' |
python -c 'import sys, json
sys.exit(0 if json.load(sys.stdin)["scheduler"]["status"] == "healthy" else 1)' ||
exit
```

If you are running under `set -e`, the explicit final `|| exit` is unnecessary. See also [What does 'set -e' mean in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script)

As noted in other answers, you can always turn a multi-line command into a one-liner; this requirement seems ill-advised anyway. If you are looking for brevity, encapsulate the long command in a function.

Answer (score 0):

if the output is always in the same order, you don't even need any dedicated JSON parser :

```
printf '%s' 

'{"db":{"status":"healthy"},"scheduler":{"fetch":
  "2024-03-12T04:32:53.060917+00:00","status":"healthy"}}' |
```

---

```
mawk NF=NF FS='"( *[}]*[,:][{]* *"|[^"]*$)' OFS=']\f\r\t['
```

---

```
{"db]
    [status]
    [healthy]
    [scheduler]
    [fetch]
    [2024-03-12T04:32:53.060917+00:00]
    [status]
    [healthy]
    [
```

Once you've delineated out the fields(columns) like this, it's very straight forward as to which component you'd like to pick out.