# Shell script raise error if any command fails

Tags: bash, error-handling

I have a shell script that runs several commands. I would like it to stop execution and rise some kind of error, that can be detected from outside, if any of these commands fails, similar to what happens in Python by default with everything. I have found that adding `set -e` at the beginning of the script should do this, but at the same time find [people discouraging to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381618/exit-a-script-on-error#comment54996061_4382179). Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, do handle errors cases by yourself for each critic commands

Comment: Does this have to be done manually for each command? I want to avoid this, as there are many commands and I only want to know if the overall execution was successful.

Comment: Try after the _shebang_: `trap 'function_in_case_of_errors' ERR`. For sure, you need to create this function.

Comment: People discourage `set -e` as a _global_ setting because it has a lot of complex rules and requires you to write unintuitive code to comply with those rules. If you just have a list of simple commands and don't want to tack `|| exit` on the end of all of them then it's okay to use `set -e`, although I recommend scoping it such that you turn the option on just for that list of commands and then disable it after.

Comment: For example: `set -e ; cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmd3; set +e` will exit if any of the three commands fail without affecting the rest of the script which may not be fully compliant with `set -e`.

Comment: Always run under `set -e`. It makes no sense not to. (Who wants random failures whoknowswhere in a script to be skipped and hidden?) Even better, `set -euo pipefail`. (Without `pipefail`, `PIPESTATUS` helps.) As for special cases, well, many of them exist and some are tricky. Let me mention one particularly tricky case: the `declare` command always succeeds. So, for example, `(set -e; declare -r a="$(exit 3)"; echo yikes;)` will succeed, despite `set -e`. (Fill in a meaningful command instead of `exit`.) A possible workaround: `(set -e; a="$(exit 3)"; echo never gets here; declare -r a;)`.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek `grep` considers it a failure if it doesn't find any matches. That's not usually a reason to stop a script that's using `grep`.

Comment: @Barmar There are way more cases like that, such as `((some_variable = 5 * another_variable))`. When `another_variable` is `0`, this is a “failure”. But such cases are rather exceptional and they work as expected when combined with `if` or `while`. The issue with `grep` is the reason why I mostly avoid it; `awk` can do most of its tasks better (although `-B` and `-A` are harder to write). When it’s inevitable, `grep something somewhere || :` is my way to go. (Unless not finding anything _is_ an actual error, which is sometimes the case.)

Comment: Side note: If there are a few trial-and-error commands about which one doesn’t care, it’s always possible to wrap them into e.g. `(set +e; can_fail_1; can_fail_2; :;)` to escape the grip of `set -e` only in a small and manageable part of the script. (Or `can_fail_1 || :; can_fail_2 || :;` etc.)

Comment: `set -e` does exactly what it is documented to do. If it works for you, use it. I found that it bites me **much** more often than it is useful, so I never use it anymore and do the error handling explicitly. After all, adding a i.e. `|| exit 41` to a command is not so much work, and it allows you (by providing different exit codes) to signal the caller, at which place the execution has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that there isn't a consistent way to tell if a command failed.

The *usual* way is to return a nonzero exit status; but in some contexts a nonzero exit status is used to mean "false" (for `if` and `while` and so on). So with `set -e`, Bash has to make a guess about what you mean; and any other automated approach would have to do likewise.

A secondary problem with `set -e` is that some of Bash's guesses are a bit counterintuitive, and some of them have changed from version to version; but realistically, I don't think any other automated approach would do much better.

So the *correct* approach, if your script is complicated and correctness matters, is for the script to consider the exit status of every single command, and take the appropriate action. A few simple options:

- end every command with `|| exit` except when that isn't specifically what you need.
- or, use `set -e`, end commands with `|| true` when you need that, and avoid `&&` almost categorically.
- or, use `trap ... ERR` as Paul Hodges suggests, end commands with `|| true` when you need that, and avoid `&&` almost categorically.

In any case, you probably want to use `set -o pipefail`, so that pipelines return a nonzero exit status if any of their components do.

Comment: ^This. The advantage of a `trap` is that you can set up a default behavior for the general case of any error you haven't explicitly handled, which can save many lines of redundant code when you *usually* want to do the same things, and still catch obscure and unexpected errors like missing or unreadable files without requiring you explicitly test every possible fail condition. You can still write custom handling around the ones that are a little different, such a the `grep` for logging purposes that you know might fail without really being a problem.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Answer (score 1):

[I recommend `trap` for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078281/raise-error-in-a-bash-script/50296873#50296873). So does the question you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4384381/8656552).

There is always a matter of style, but if writing for anything more than a one-off, I almost always put some sort of `trap` like the one mentioned in the above link, and then manually handle any case where a known fail is ok.

Generally, a test will consume an error, so this *won't* trigger the `trap`.

```
$: ( trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR
> if grep unfound_string somefile # doesn't exit
> then echo found it
> else echo here I am, not dying.
> fi
> echo still here
> )
grep: somefile: No such file or directory
here I am, not dying.
still here
```

But this does...

```
$: ( trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR
> grep unfound_string somefile # DOES exit
> echo I shall not say this.
> )
grep: somefile: No such file or directory
I DIE
```

If you know you don't want a bare error to be fatal on a specific statement, you can catch that known case with `||:` -

```
$: ( trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR
> grep unfound_string somefile ||: # error ok here, always return 0
> echo I SHALL say this now.
> )
grep: somefile: No such file or directory
I SHALL say this now.
```

As mentioned in comments, my simplistic example uses a fixed error message and exit code in double quotes, which can be much improved in any real script. Let's Look at some more elaborate examples.

I frequently source a `tools` file with some boilerplate code I include in scripts. Here's a simplified version:

```
$: cat tools
trap 'echo "Bye!"' EXIT
trap ' ec=$?;
  echo >&2 "ERROR $ec in ${nodeName:-$(uname -n)}:$0( ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}${FUNCNAME:+[$FUNCNAME]} ) at line $((LINENO-1)): [$BASH_COMMAND]";
  exit $ec; ' ERR
set -Eu          # -u exits with error on unset variable; -E makes functions inherit error trap
f() { crashme; } # command doesn't exist

$: cat tst
#! bash
. tools
grep ^X $0 ||:               # error ignored, never fails here
(($#)) && f                  # fails here if args passed
echo "required='$required'"  # fails here if not set
grep ^X $0                   # always fails if it gets here
echo done

$: ./tst x # runs f, reports file and func of error LINENO
tools: line 6: crashme: command not found
ERROR 127 in myPC:./tst( tools[f] ) at line 6: [crashme]
Bye!

$: required=FOUND ./tst  
required='FOUND'
ERROR 1 in myPC:./tst( ./tst ) at line 6: [grep ^X $0]
Bye!

$: ./tst # no trap debugging info here...
./tst: line 5: required: unbound variable
Bye!
```

Note that last one as a good example of the reasons people advise caution and testing in any approach - `set -u` doesn't trigger the error trap in my system (but does still trigger the EXIT trap).

Also, note some of the odd complexities needed for correct reporting: `LINENO` in this setup needs to be retroactively adjusted to correctly show the line that had the error. (A better way would have been a function call with arguments like [iheggie's, here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/650070/322892), but I wanted to show the problem.)

There's a lot to take into account. This is one reason some people suggest that you use another language for more complex tasks. Sometimes you use the tools available, and make it work. As with anything, *YMMV*.

Comment: To be clear -- I don't think `trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR` avoids any of the problematic quirks of `set -e`, does it? The difference is just that it prints `I DIE` before exiting, instead of exiting silently?

Comment: Agreed. I created a simplistic trap to demonstrate, though the links show more elaborated use. The point was that you can execute arbitrary code on any uncaught error, but a *handled* error doesn't trigger it.

Comment: I see. I just find this answer very confusing, because `trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR` doesn't address the reasons that people recommend against `set -e`. So while it's totally fine to recommend `trap "echo I DIE; exit 1" ERR` as an improvement over `set -e`, I think you need to be upfront about what it does and does not accomplish.

Comment: It accomplishes what you write it to accomplish. `set -e` dies on what it sees as errors. If that works for you, go with it. `trap ... ERR` has similar flaws based on the definition of an error as a nonzero exit code, but gives an opportunity to do additional checking and/or customize a response, or build a more complex check on EXIT or DEBUG, etc, perhaps in conjunction with `set -e`. I'm sorry to confuse you; if you'd care to offer a better example I'll happily edit, but there are examples in the links (mine and others'.) For more, please c.f. my comment on your answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice approach and for anyone reading this in future there are several variables you could print from inside the trap to help identify where the error occurred, see the answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462156/133219. You could also consider doing `trap 'ec=$?; echo "whatever"; exit "$ec"' ERR` so your script exits with  the same error code that caused the trap to fire instead of always exiting with `1` on an error which also could provide the caller with useful information on what failed inside the script and why.