Why bash doesn't fail the script after a failure inside brackets?
This is the code in a.sh (there is no foo command available, it is an intentional error):
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

{
    foo
    echo 1
} || echo 2

I expect it to print 2, but it prints this:
$ ./a.sh
+ foo
./a.sh: line 5: foo: command not found
+ echo 1
1

Why and how to fix this? I know that I can connect foo and echo 1 with the &&, but I'm expecting set -e to do the job.

But it does fail. Why would it not?

The 1 should not be printed (because of failure at foo)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381618/exit-a-script-on-error   Commands whose status is tested by a conditional (such as if, && or ||) do not terminate the script (otherwise the conditional would be pointless). An idiom for the occasional command whose failure doesn't matter is command-that-may-fail || true. You can also turn set -e off for a part of the script with set +e.

So, based on that, echo 1 line should be if [ "$?" = "0" ] then;   echo 1 else echo 2 fi after foo error

The behavior of set -e is very unintuitive (and not even consistent between different bash versions) -- never count on it to do something reasonable! See BashFAQ 105: "Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?"

Re "I'm expecting set -e to do the job": Due to bash's MO (commingling failure reporting with conditionals) the implementation of set -e is incondite at best. Use it for convenience (e.g. to better locate the cause of an error) but never make your code rely on it.


Why bash doesn't fail the script after a failure inside brackets?

Because the command is part of || pipeline, where set -e has on effect.
